# Collapsing Menu in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to display menu items in a GridView-like container on top of the screen with scrollable content below. On scroll I want the GridView to shrink and resize and lock on top of the screen. In other words, imagine a CollapsingToolbarLayout where instead of an expanded image there's a Grid of menu items and instead of the collapsed toolbar there's a single bar of menu items.

Expanded:

[image]

Collapsed:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this behavior? What would be the easiest way to do so? Any libs? I would necessarily need to use a GridView, as the number of entries is limited I'm quite flexible in building the layout. Thanks for any tips and hints.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try to create two different linear layouts. One for collapsed and one for expanded state. Then manipulate them with [setVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int))

Fill the layouts with apropriate data in onCreate.

If you don't know the exact amout of elements you want to hold inside you expandable field(is is not fixed), consider using something like gridView

Comment: Hi thanks. Yeah that would be the most straightforward solution. Nevertheless I was thinking of something more fluid (animated) then just switching between two layouts.

Comment: your case is very specific. You are not only hiding some items, but showing others. In other words, simple expanding animation should be extended. Consider writing some custom fade animation or use any animation library you like. https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations this is my favourite.